# Deleted Instance passed to Merge

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I've got this problem with hibernate:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted instance passed to merge: [es.melit.celimac.domain.Alzado#<null>]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:888)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:869)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:298)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy239.merge(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:511)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:515)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:500)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:477)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
... 174 common frames omitted
```

This error appears me when I try to save the entity "Alzado"

"Alzado" has a relationship with "Edificio" oneToMany :

Edificio.java

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "edificio", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JsonIgnore
private Set<Alzado> alzados = new HashSet<>();
```

Alzado.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "alzado")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Alzado implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "codigo")
private String codigo;

@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "edificio_id")
private Edificio edificio;

@Column(name = "archivo")
private String archivo;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "alzado", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JsonIgnore
private Set<Modulo> modulos = new HashSet<>();
/* GETTERS AND SETTERS */
```

I tried to put cascade= CascadeType.MERGE and nothing, I tried too
 cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST}
and not works. I dunno what try more...

Thanks

Comment: Is this thread any help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358407/org-hibernate-objectdeletedexception-deleted-object-would-be-re-saved-by-cascad

Comment: Yes, before I used orphanRemoval and same error, but thanks.

Comment: are you deleting an object before in the same transaction?

Comment: Yes I deleted, Alzados and later I set a new Alzado.

Comment: Did the issue resolved ?? I am also facing similar issue what is the solution